# Looking for a better way to create reference codes in Sqlite3

Tags: python, sqlite

I need to create reference codes for tables in Sqlite3.

They will follow the format "P-1000" and will increment by one when each new project is added.

I have the following code to find the last reference code and increment it. Is there a simpler way or easier to handle custom identifiers like this?

I don't know if Sqlite3 or another querying language have built in ways of handling this sort of thing.

```
def find_last_reference_code(self):
    query = QueryBuilder(self.table) \
        .select(['reference_code as last_reference_code']) \
        .from_() \
        .where('id = (select max(id) from projects)')
    self.execute(**query.build())
    return self.get_one()

def make_next_reference_code(self):
    last_project = self.find_last_reference_code()
    last_reference_code = last_project["last_reference_code"] if last_project else 'P-1000'
    reference_code = 'P-' + str(int(last_reference_code[2:]) + 1)
    return reference_code
```

*Don't worry about the `QueryBuilder` stuff it's just a wrapper I wrote around SQL queries, but if it helps here is how it works: https://github.com/sarcoma/Invoicing/tree/master/invoicing/query_builder*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest adding an insert trigger similar to the following:

```
  create trigger insert_refcode after insert on Table_name
  begin
     update Table_name
     set reference_code = printf('P-%04d', id+999)
     where rowid=new.rowid;
  end
```

Comment: Glad to have helped.